# How to get Label view in ViewModel to set accessibility focus in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, accessibility

I have `Label` in view, I need that `Label`'s view in my `ViewModel`. I am using Dependency Service to set focus on Controls for Accessibility service, DS requires `view` as a param.

This is my Label

```
<Label
    AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree="{Binding ShowNoResults}"
    IsVisible="{Binding ShowNoResults}"
    Text="{Binding ResultsHeader}"/>
```

I tried `Command` but Label doesn't support command. Below code also not working

```
var view = GetView() as HomeworkView;
```

I am getting `view` always `null`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your VM shouldn't be directly accessing your View.

Comment: @Jason - Then how can I set focus on `noResult Label`, if specific operation is not returning anything.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do - setting focus on an element that doesn't accept keyboard input won't accomplish anything.  I'm not an accessibility expert, but I'd suggest having your VM raise a custom event that your view subscribes to that will tell it where to set the accessibility focus.

Comment: @Jason - Accessibility is for blind people. The Label text will be announced Like no result found, for that, Label need focus.  Let me explore more.

Comment: Why do you need to set accessbility focus manually? Can you accomplish your goal using [Xamarin Forms - Automation Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/accessibility/automation-properties)?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - These works when you tap on the control. I need to have the speak/focus on random control.

Comment: OK. Mohammad's answer is the approach to use. I made an answer that shows in more detail what to do. (I would have edited their answer, but there were so many changes/additions, that didn't seem appropriate.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure what are you trying to achieve, but you can't access the View elements from you view model.

If you want to do something with the control, you can use the messaging center to do it, here is an example

in your ViewModel

```
MessagingCenter.Send(this, "your message here");
```

then in your page, you need to subscribe to this message from that view model and do the desired action

```
MessagingCenter.Instance.Unsubscribe<ViewModelClassNamedel>(this, "your message here");    
MessagingCenter.Instance.Subscribe<ViewModelClassName>(this, "your message here", (data) =>
    {
        this.youControlName.Focus();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

More detail added to [Mohammad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68364258/199364).

[Message Center doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center).

In your ViewModel (with class name "YourViewModel"):

```
// Here we use control name directly.
// OR could make an "enum" with a value for each control.
string controlName = ...;
MessagingCenter.Send<YourViewModel>(this, "focus", controlName);
```

then in your page, subscribe to this message and do the desired action

.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnAppearing() {
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    // Unsubscribe before Subscribe ensures you don't Subscribe twice, if the page is shown again.
    MessagingCenter.Instance.Unsubscribe<YourViewModel>(this, "focus");    
    MessagingCenter.Instance.Subscribe<YourViewModel>(this, "focus", (controlName) =>
    {
        View v = null;
        switch (controlName) {
        case "name1":
            v = this.name1;
            break;
        case "name2":
            v = this.name2;
            break;
        }

        if (v != null) {
            //v.Focus();
            // Tell VM to use v as view.
            ((YourViewModel)BindingContext).SetFocus(v);
        }
    });
}

protected override void OnDisappearing() {
    MessagingCenter.Instance.Unsubscribe<YourViewModel>(this, "focus");    

    base.OnDisappearing();
}
```

If need to pass `View v` back to VM, because that has the logic to use it:

```
public class YourViewModel
{

    public void SetFocus(View view)
    {
       ... your code that needs label's view ...
    }
}
```

Not tested. Might need some slight changes. Might need

```
...(this, "focus", (sender, controlName) =>
```

instead of

```
...(this, "focus", (controlName) =>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Simple approach, if there is only ONE View that is needed in VM.

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public View ViewToFocus { get; set; }

    // The method that needs ViewToFocus.
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        ...
        if (ViewToFocus != null)
            ... do something with it ...
    }
}

public class YourView
{
    public YourView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
        // After BindingContext is set.
        ((YourViewModel)BindingContext).ViewToFocus = this.yourLabelThatShouldBeFocused;
    }

}
```

ALTERNATIVE: It might be cleaner/more robust to set ViewToFocus in page's OnAppearing, and clear it in OnDisappearing. This ensures it is never used while the page is not visible (or in some delayed action after the page has gone away). I would probably do it this way.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    ((YourViewModel)BindingContext).ViewToFocus = this.yourLabelThatShouldBeFocused;
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    ((YourViewModel)BindingContext).ViewToFocus = null;
    base.OnDisappearing();
}
```

Comment: First issue in viewmodel `no overloads takes 3 argument for Send` 2nd one in `OnAppearing` in `Subscribe` there is no method like `lbl.focus` rather I need to use this line `DependencyService.Get<ISetAccessibleFocus>().AccessibilityFocus(noResultLblHeader);` How can I fix this

Comment: @R15 - Maybe `Send<YourViewModel, string>`. You might need to also change the Subscribe/Unsubscribe to `<YourViewModel, string>`. I attempted to adapt code from an example. You'll have to experiment or search for more information.

Comment: @R15 - I've edited to show how to pass label's view back to a function in `YourViewModel`.

Comment: @R15 What is noResultLblHeader? You want to use `DependencyService.Get<ISetAccessibleFocus>().AccessibilityFocus(noResultLblHeader);` if specific operation happened?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT - Yes, if search returning no result then we are showing `Label` in middle of screen like `No Result Found`. `noResultLblHeader` is a Label name. When no records found I need to announce that label using Dep Service.

Comment: @R15 - Oh, you only need to do this for ONE specific label? Are you sure you need to use accessibility to do this?  All `Views` have a `Focus()` method (inherited from `VisualElement`). You could [use Binding and a Trigger to invoke that from VM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215477/199364).

Comment: @R15 - I've added an UPDATE that shows an alternative way to tell VM about a specific View.